# How to lazy load images in a scroll view

Tags: xamarin

I want to show a scroll view that has fairly large number of thumbnails. eg: https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/sddJ5KHoGDbZfx8jcNey4iahmu0=/0x0:1395x1171/1200x800/filters:focal(587x475:809x697)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/57064313/Screen_Shot_2015-09-07_at_9.11.34_AM.0.0.png

I want to load the view as fast as possible without delaying it until all images are loaded. This essentially means I need to lazy load image content. While each image is downloaded, a placeholder image (fetched locally) should be shown. I certainly know how to do this from scratch, but wanted to know if there are standard solutions available. Can I setup Xamarin.Forms.Image class to get this behavior?

Comment: Image loading, caching & transforming library for Xamarin and Windows : https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason for which you want to use a ScrollView specifically ?

From what you're describing, it looks like you should actually be working with a ListView instead (which will improve performance by a LOT if you have a large list of images).
Then, like @SushiHangover said, there is FFImageLoading that can help you work with these images, or you can create you own Image class, to implement a custom solution on both android and iOS.
Glide is a faily easy to use solution for Android, and SDWebImage is also a good solution for iOS.